# Extract (too light) purple form an image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I'm using python and cv2 to extract purple text from images like these:

[image: myimage1]

[image: myimage2]

I'm using this code:

```py
image = cv2.imread("myimage.jpg")
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

hsv_color1 = np.asarray([130, 0, 0]) #light purple
hsv_color2 = np.asarray([150, 255, 255]) #dark purple

mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, hsv_color1, hsv_color2)
```

The first example seems working pretty well. This is the result:

[image: myimage1Result]

However, in the second example (and many others images), the purple seems to be too light. This is the result:

[image: myimage2Result]

I'm quite a noob and can't find a solution. Is there any way to improve extraction when purple is too light?

Comment: Welcome to the joys of image analysis. It's incredibly hard to create an analysis pipeline that works well with heterogeneous/non-standardized data. Even if you do create a set of instructions to detect whether the image is too bright and then adjust contrast accordingly, there's always the chance that you get a new image with a different pattern that's not properly caught by your pipeline. I've come to expect a certain failure % for most moderately difficult image analysis applications. Machine learning is a viable alternative but it requires training and even then is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score -2):

I don't use python anymore so I don't remember much about that library but what you can do is increase the contrast of the image.

Comment: that won't work. the information just isn't in the picture. the picture would have to be taken differently (don't overexpose). and that only works if the ink on the paper is actually there. if it isn't, no amount of simple image processing can fix this.